# Disable sliding feature of tray icons

Tags: fedora, gnome

[image]

I want to disable sliding feature of these icons. I want them to be static, you know just like Windows perhaps. When I hover my mouse over them they slide & it greatly annoys me to again relocate my mouse pointer. I just want to get rid of the sliding feature.